# hostname and hostname -f are backwards?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, hostname, hosts, hosts-file

When I run the command `hostname` (on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Server) it returns 'mail.mydomain.com'

When I run `hostname -f` I get 'mail' as a response.

These seem backwards to me, shouldn't `hostname -f` return the FQDN?  Where did I misconfigure this?

Comment: Please posts the contents of /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `hostname -f` should return the FQDN. Try:

- In `/etc/hostname` put the "short" hostname (`mail`).
- In `/etc/resolv.conf` put `domain mydomain.com`.

There are probably other ways to do it; that's just how I have my system configured (and it seems to work).

Comment: The changes to /etc/hostname worked beautifully.  When running hostname -f I still only get `mail` instead of the FQDN.  I did add `domain mydomain.com` to resolv.conf as well. (Rebooted for good measure to test too. :)

Comment: I think the next step would be to check `/etc/hosts` and add an entry there, if appropriate. Let us know!

Comment: Had to add the entry to hosts as well `127.0.0.1 mail.mydomain.com mail` :)  Thank you for the help, couldn't have done this without you!